# JQuery add on(load) event to dynamically created elements

Tags: jquery

I'm building a page that dynamically loads content coming from a database.
After the content is loaded, I would like an event to be triggered to perform some actions.

I can't use the window.onload event because that one fires when the initial page is loaded, before the content is being added.

I've been trying to add a load command to the variable I'm appending to my div but it doesn't fire.

I'm assuming I'm forgetting something stupid, but I can't find what.

```
  var html = '<div class="messageContent"><img src="http://www.microadagencies.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Dont-be-Evil-by-Google.jpg" /></div>\r\n';

  var objToAppend = $(html).on('load', function() {
    alert('loaded')
  });

  $('#test').append(objToAppend);
```

Can anybody spot what I'm doing wrong?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/215yuxyk

Comment: div elements don't have load events.  You'll have to add said event to the elements that DO have load events, such as the image element. Note however that it's possible that it'l be too late to add said event by the time you're able to if the image is already cached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your JavaScript add function as follows

```
    function add() {
        var tempdiv = $('<div class="messageContent">');
        var tempimg = $('<img src="http://www.microadagencies.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Dont-be-Evil-by-Google.jpg" /></div>\r\n');
        tempimg.on('load', function () {
            alert('loaded');
        });

        tempdiv.append(tempimg);

        $('#test').append(tempdiv);
    }
```

Here is the working fiddler: https://jsfiddle.net/215yuxyk/3/

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your example fiddle. However I have an additional question. How could I add other code after this image? If I need to add another div with more information in it? So for example if I need to add <div id="anotherId">some more dynamic content coming from the database but which doesn't need a load-event</div> ?

Comment: var tempdiv1=$('<div/>').text('sample text'); tempdiv.append(tempdiv1)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to bind a live event to the document.

```
$('html').on('DOMNodeInserted DOMNodeRemoved', function(e) {
// your code
});
```

This will bind an event to the html and changes to DOM will trigger the above method.